# Why is that my ubuntu clock is not working during the time I put in sleep mode

Tags: suspend, time, clock

When I set time in ubuntu it's working fine, but soon after putting in sleep mode, it's not working.

Let's say the time is 3:00PM and I suspended the laptop for 2 hours.
It's now 5:00PM but when the laptop resumes it says it's still 3:00PM.
After another 10 minutes it will show the time 3:10PM.

Comment: I would dare to say that you have a bug. What shows `timedatectl`?

Comment: I have the same problem (running Ubuntu on my Mac inside VMWare Fusion. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

After over a decade using Ubuntu on my laptop, this happened to me only today.

I don't know what happened (aside from the fact that is really cold today ), but this command corrected the time.

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd.service
```